# Scraping Hover box from Tableau Dashboard using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mousehover

I am trying to scrape the hover box information from this website:
https://www.bcbs.com/the-health-of-america/health-index/impact-high-cholesterol

I have already tried to use the `TableauScraper` package in Python but it is returning the wrong data. Coconino County should have a value of "15.2% greater" or some derivative of the actual county data but there is no value I can add, subtract, divide, or multiply to make the data coherent.

[Data Returned from Tableauscraper package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP38w.png)

Here is my code from the TableauScraper library:

```
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.bcbs.com/the-health-of-america/health-index/impact-high-cholesterol'

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
workbook = ts.getWorkbook()

for t in workbook.worksheets:
    # if ts.getWorksheet(t.name).data.shape[0] != 0:
    print(f'worksheet name : {t.name}')

ws = ts.getWorksheet('County Map')

cholesterol_data = ws.data
cholesterol_data.to_csv('../data/cholesterol.csv', index=False)
```

This failure of using TableauScraper has lead me to scrape the website manually. When in inspector mode, when I hover over a county and press F8, I can pause the inspection and inspect the hover box. However, whenever I move the mouse again, the HTML updates, and the data is lost.

[Wanted Elements in HTML when Paused Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gGIC.png)

I have also tried inspecting to see if there was a JSON response but it doesn't look like it. It seems like the Tableauscraper package is scraping this 1.1MB file and it doesn't look like the "15.2% greater" values are in the file.

[File that Tableauscraper scrapes that might hold the raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceqJ6.png)

So my question remains, is there a way to mimic mouse hovers and then scrape the HTML? I'm open to almost any technology but python, and more specifically BeautifulSoup, is my bread and butter. Once I find a way to mimic mouse movements, I have no problem scraping the web page from there.

Comment: It seems it's only accessible from the US so I can't try it out (even with proxy). If you open chrome development console / network tab, when you hover a county, is there some call like `/render-tooltip-server` that returns the data ?  Is there some command call that contains the data after the 1.1MB file call ?

Comment: It doesn't seem so. It looks like when you load the page, it loads the data directly into the dashboard (not sure how that works). Moving the mouse around doesn't download anything. Nothing else comes through the network unless I click on a specific county (this updates the dashboard and redownloads that 1.1MB file).

Comment: can you right click "copy as curl" on the 1.1Mb request and paste it in a github gist or something that you can share